# Cannot archive an iOS project with cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I've tried to archive my iOS project, but I've got errors with some pods. Versions in my project's and pods' target are equals. Here is a screenshot from xcode, thank you!

[image: screenshot from xcode]

[image: screenshot of podfile]

Comment: Please check your pod libraries deployment target that supports to your project deployment target.

Comment: Can you show us your podfile?

Comment: Are you using workspace while creating the archive?

Comment: yes, of course, I'm using workspace

Comment: CocoaPods 1.1.0 just came out with a bunch of Xcode8 fixes, try running `pod install` with the new version see if something changes

Comment: I've just tried to do it, but it didn't help me

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the header files are not being found.Try adding the Pods framework path to your projects 'Header Search Paths'. Header Search Paths can be found in the  build settings section of your project

Comment: Header Search Paths are correct, I've checked. This project could archive on my 21.5'' mac, but couldn't archive on 27'' mac

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution. This errors appeared because I have had two versions of xcode on my iMac. After deleting one of them the problem was solved.